# Addition of JavaScript inline comment breaks surrounding MVC/Kendo behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working toward developing an app that will allow the user to enter data about a thing.  That thing can be either full or partial and pretty much all the other stuff they need to input changes from that inflection point.  I've successfully built the app to the point that everything works perfectly when the following JavaScript function is called after the user makes this choice:

```
function selectedFullOrPartial()
{
    var pullDown = $("#fullOrPartial");
    pullDown.data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
    if (pullDown.val() == 1)
    {
        alert("You chose full");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You chose partial");
    }
}
```

However, when I write that function like this instead:

```
function selectedFullOrPartial()
{
    var pullDown = $("#fullOrPartial");
    pullDown.data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
    if (pullDown.val() == 1)
    {
        //They chose full
        alert("You chose full");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You chose partial");
    }
}
```

It's enough to change the behaviour of the surrounding environment to the point where the dialogue to select full/partial never even appears (an entry is generated with null as its value at the time it should).  A quick look at the console finds the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

Another note of interest:  Block comments work just fine, whether they exist on a single line or multiple.

How is it possible for the simple addition of a comment to break any kind of code?  I thought they were always just ignored by everything when compiling.  Do I have any options besides the obvious workaround of converting all inline comments to block comments?

Comment: Is there some kind of broken minifier operating on your code? Is that what the code looks like when it actually makes it out to the browser?

Comment: ^^^ this. Look at what the code is **in the browser**, not the source code you edit. Clearly some tool, somewhere, is messing this up.

Comment: The minifier makes a lot of sense if block comments are fine

Comment: Yup, the entire function I wrote is condensed down to a single line of code (alongside a whole whack load of stuff before and after it).  Well, that answers the questions of how and why it's happening.  It also makes me assume I can't do anything about it.

Oh well - block comments are nice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the environment I'm working in causes my entire JavaScript function to condense down to a single line of code (alongside a bunch of stuff automatically generated around it).  Since the line doesn't end after my inline comment, it actually wipes out a fair bit more stuff and it's this that causes the errant behaviour.

It seems that the workaround of only using block comments is the way to go on this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

var pullDown = $("#fullOrPartial");
    pullDown.data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
    if (pullDown.data("kendoDropDownList").value() == 1)
    {
        //They chose full
        alert("You chose full");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You chose partial");
    }

changed val() to value().
```

Comment: Changing 'val()' to 'value()' results in the same behaviour when an inline comment is included and incorrect behaviour when it is not (the drop down menu is disabled, but no alert is triggered).